# Why do I need to repeat writing `mut` the second time?

Tags: rust

A mutable variable is declared and initialized with the keyword `mut`, but when it's used in the next line of code, the keyword `mut` must be repeated;

```
let mut guess = String::new();

io::stdin()
    .read_line(&mut guess)
    .expect("Failed to read line");
```

My expectation is that once a variable is declared and initialized as mutable, it remains to be so. Is this a syntactic sugar or is there a specific reason for this?

I would expect the above code to be like this:

```
let mut guess = String::new();

io::stdin()
    .read_line(&guess)
    .expect("Failed to read line");
```

Note that I have omitted the `mut` keyword in the call to `read_line`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I strongly encourage you to go back and re-read [*The Rust Programming Language*, second edition](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/), specifically the section on [references and borrowing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html#mutable-references).

There are two types of references: immutable and mutable. Even if a variable *may* be mutated, you can choose to get an immutable reference to it. You make this choice by saying `&foo` or `&mut foo`.

This capability is important to allow you to adhere to the [rules of references](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html#the-rules-of-references):

> 1. At any given time, you can have either but not both of:
>
>    - One mutable reference.
>    - Any number of immutable references.

As [`BufRead::read_line`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.BufRead.html#method.read_line) requires a mutable reference to a `String`, you need to say `&mut guess`.

Comment: To expand on the quoted text, writing `&x` can be very useful for an immutable `x` because it allows creating multiple references to `x` simultaneously. If every `&x` automatically meant `&mut x` when `x` is mutable, you wouldn't be able to create more than one reference to `x` in a single scope.